# DB2 - Cannot connect to or drop database. But it exists on disk

Tags: database, db2

Hi so when I try to drop a database "sample" in db2 in CLPPlus it says the database alias name or database name "sample" could not be found. But when I type the

```
list database directory
```

command i see that it is there. it is also on disk, i see it where i designated the location of the database when i made it. I cannot connect to it and I cannot drop it.

just extra info... don't know if it will be useful, but i uncatalogged the database and when i try to catalog it, it says the database was not found in the local database directory

Comment: i still dont know what was wrong, but i just recreated the database and its fine now

Comment: How were you trying to drop the database?  `DROP DATABASE` is not a valid CLPPlus command.

Answer (score 0):

Are you dealing with the file system where the database is stored? Normally, a database is created in two directories, one is in the instance whe the database files are stored (history, lock control, configuration, etc.) and another for the tablespaces (catalog).

Are you sure you see both of them?
I think just one of these locations is still on your hard disk, and that is not enought to connect to the database.

Did you uninstalle (drop) the instance?

In your case it is better to uncatalog everything, drop the instance and rebuild the configuration.